# Locking an empty's position to a vertex with shrinkwrap constraint

Tags: vertices, constraints, cloth-simulation, shrinkwrap

My problem is that I have a rope that has a cloth animation, so it's hanging between two points. The rope is a single edge with several vertices on it. When I try to attach emptys to the vertex with the shrinkwrap modifier (nearest vertex), it works for a while but when the rope starts moving, the emptys start teleporting between different vertices because the vertex before is not the closest one at the moment. How could I make the emptys stay on a particular vertex without them teleporting? Is there an alternative for the shrinkwrap constraint made for a similar purpose?

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with parenting the empty to a vertex:

1. Select the empty
2. Select the mesh that has the targeted vertex
3. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd>
4. Select the targeted vertex
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
6. Select *Make Vertex Parent*
7. (Optional) Tab out to object mode, bake animation, select *Clear Parents*, *Visual Keying* and you have an empty moving with the vertex without the empty being attached to the mesh.